# How to name the classes that caries data to a different layer?

Tags: naming, naming-standards

When I retrieve data from database I name the class as `Model`, for example `UserModel`.

When I send data to the View I name the class as `ViewModel`, for example `UserSettingsViewModel`.

How to name the class that exchange data between layers?

Comment: Mention few options that you think are correct, but not sure which to choose from. Then the community will know what you are thinking and can help accordingly.

Comment: I use [DTO or data transfer object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object) for data that travels from business layer to view layer.

Comment: The layer is an adater though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My suggestion is to omit the 'Model' suffix from your main class. I have seen 'DataTransport' or 'DT' classes, but generally you shouldnt need a separate class for this.

example classes

- Database Table : User
- read into : DataReader (from db client)
- which populates : User
- which populates : UserEditingViewModel
- which binds to : UserEditingView

or in an api where you send data over the wire

- Database Table : User
- read into : DataReader
- which populates : User
- which is serialised to : string (json/xml)
- which is deserialised to : User

Comment: How I can learn more about these things? I have read Code Complete but this book is very old and I would like to find something similar for today technology, mostly for web.

Answer (score 0):

A Gateway suffix is also used, for example DataAccessGateway between the DAL and the business logic layer is responsible to convert the data to a model object that is received by the business logic that works with a model of the data